# Is there a way to create pandas DataFrameGroupBy from multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have three lists, one with clients ids, one with months and one with categories.

```
clients_ids = [1, ..., 130000]
months = [1, ..., 12]
categories = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And I want to create pandas GroupBy Object, from these lists, that will look like this

[image]
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Your output is ambiguous, please provide the desired output as a DataFrame object

Comment: Do you want to generate a [`product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) of the lists?

Comment: that looks closer to a pivot table.

Comment: @mozway didn't know that such function exists in pandas, thank you!